# ./configure is showing no such file or directory?

Tags: 14.04, privman

I want to install `privman` downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/seancomeau/privman).

When I run make command after `./autogen.sh` and `./configure`, it shows me:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master'
Making all in config
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master/config'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master/config'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master/src'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `config_parse.h', needed by `all'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/syam/Downloads/privman-master'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you extract the files to a directory and are you currently `cd`ed into that directory in the terminal?

Comment: @Zacharee1 yeah

Comment: @syamkumarDorjee nice. The README will tell you what to do ;=) and yes likely to be "./autogen.sh"

Comment: @Rinzwind syam@syam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ cd privman-master/
syam@syam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/privman-master$ ls

acinclude.m4  automake.txt  config.h.in   INSTALL      man     src
AUTHORS       ChangeLog     configure.in  LICENSE      NEWS    tests
autogen.sh    config        etc           Makefile.am  README  TODO

Comment: @Rinzwind ./autogen.sh shows
./autogen.sh: 3: ./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
./autogen.sh: 4: ./autogen.sh: autoheader: not found
./autogen.sh: 6: ./autogen.sh: autoconf: not found
./autogen.sh: 7: ./autogen.sh: automake: not found

Comment: Please add them to the question (code in comments is hard to read ;))

Answer (score 3):

You need to run

```
./autogen.sh
```

fisrt to create the `./configure` script.

Comment: still not working 

./autogen.sh shows

./autogen.sh: 3: ./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
./autogen.sh: 4: ./autogen.sh: autoheader: not found
./autogen.sh: 6: ./autogen.sh: autoconf: not found
./autogen.sh: 7: ./autogen.sh: automake: not found

Comment: almost ;-) seems it is `./configure.in` to create `configure`

Comment: `configure.in` is not normally an executable file: it's read by `autogen`. I think the real problem is the OP doesn't have `automake` installed (there may be other problems, since the git repo appears to be 9 years old)

Comment: @syamkumarDorjee: You need to install the packages `automake` and `autoconf`.